# mysql SELECT WHERE string contains characters

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a table field `events` which can contains:

- Only a sequence of number, for example: `45`
- or a sequence of number divided by the symbol `|`, for example `55|65|76`

I think i have to use `LIKE`, but i don't know how. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Here's your help: fix your table design and split those |-separated chars into a proper child table. And no, we're not here to do your job for you. Try and write the query yourself, and we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: What is you question? Using `LIKE` what do you want to search?

Comment: I want to search a number in that table field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `CONCAT` to add a pipe `|` before and after your field, and then using a `LIKE` search.  Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
WHERE concat('|',field,'|') like '%|45|%'
```

- [SQL FIddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4706/1)

However, I highly recommend trying to normalize your data.  Considering storing these in separate rows which would make searching/maintaining much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your query, use:

```
Select * from tbl where events='45' or events like '%|45' or events like '%|45|%' or   
events like '45|%'
```

but this is terribly slow and should not be used.

Instead, do as Marc B states and create a child table `events (ID, event)`.