# MySQL string 'contains' functionality

Tags: mysql, string

Yes, this is a question that has been beaten to death, yet I believe its a tad different.

Please consider this MySQL table `test`:

[image]

The desired resultset is:

[image]

In words, how can the first 3 records (`id`s 1, 2, 5) be selected using ***exactly*** this string - '**Cinema, Entertainment**' and in ***one single query***?  That is, how can `A` be compared with the string above and have it return the record if even *one 'word'* matches?

Have tried the following:

- `SELECT * FROM test WHERE A LIKE "%Cinema, Entertainment%"`
- `SELECT * FROM test WHERE INSTR(A, 'Cinema, Entertainment') > 0`

Both return just the first record, doing an exact match.

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE A LIKE '%Cinema%' OR A LIKE '%Entertainment%'` does work, but I do not want to tokenize the available string. The string could also have multiple `CSV`s.

Very new to regular expressions, and cannot seem to form the right query.

Have seen these cool answers,:

- [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121630/how-to-write-mysql-query-where-a-contains-a-or-b)
- [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602252/mysql-query-string-contains)
- [SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775657/mysql-select-where-string-contains-characters)
- [SO 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389293/sql-query-to-find-if-a-string-contains-part-of-the-value-in-column)

...but still struggling.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You realize you're using the wrong data structure, right?

Comment: I think you need to go for full text search

Comment: @shmosel, thank you! You mean there should be no `CSV` in a single column?

Comment: @VikasUmrao, thanks, but beats me. Database newbie that I am, not sure what _full text search_ means...

Comment: Downvoters, please hint as to why your downvote.

Comment: Definitely not. You should use a `tag` table and another mapping table for each combination of `test.id, tag.id`. That will ensure data integrity and it will give you a lot more query flexibility.

Comment: Cool, thanks @shmosel, will use this principle next time.

Comment: You need to first define your column as full text index... and then give a try for the answer given by @Naga below

Comment: @VikasUmrao, thanks! It all works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will help on this requirement. But you need to make sure the A column  FULLTEXT Indexed.

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD FULLTEXT(`A`);

SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE (match(A) against('Cinema, Entertainment' IN BOOLEAN MODE));
```

Comment: Thanks @Naga. `SELECT * FROM test WHERE match(A) against('Cinema, Entertainment' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` works.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to get your desired result.

```
select * from `test` where find_in_set('Cinema',`A`) OR find_in_set('Entertainment',`A`);
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b290/3)

Comment: Thanks! But like I said, I do not want to _tokenize_ the available string "Cinema, Entertainment". However, a new learning this.